# Turning off SIM lock via ADB service calls or similar method

Tags: android, security, adb, android-10.0

I am investigating changing the pin associated with a SIM on Android 10.
this is done with this service call
`service call phone 8 i32 xxxx s16 xxxx s16 xxxx`
This changes the pin when the simId, puk and pin are entered respectively.
This turns on the SIM lock, which is somewhat expected, but i am unclear on how to unset this lock via ADB.
Would anybody here be familiar with a solution? Is it Via ADB service calls similar to how i set the pin in the first place?
Any information would be great!

I have looked at the aidl files associated with the SIM pin, none seem to mention "unsetting" or "disabling" the lock.

*update: using AT+CLCK command seems to be able to clear the lock screen on reboot, the command is a bit odd, but it is `echo "AT+CLCK=\"SC\",0,\"pin\"\r" > /dev/smd8`
It unset the SIM1 lock screen, but not SIM2.